# Trouble installing libnet-0.10.11 on Ubuntu-9.10

Tags: ubuntu, libnet

Here's what I did...
    #tar -xzvf libnet-0.10.11.tar.gz
    #cd libnet

Then I copied the linux.mak file to the port.mak file in the parent directory.
Then, as the documentation says, I used make in the present directory...

```
naman@naman-laptop:~/Desktop/Software/libnet$ make
make -C lib/ lib
make[1]: Entering directory `/home/naman/Desktop/Software/libnet/lib'
gcc -O2 -Wall -Werror -Wno-unused -Wstrict-prototypes -Wmissing-prototypes -Wmissing-declarations -g -I../include -Iinclude -DTARGET_LINUX   -c -o core/config.o core/config.c
cc1: warnings being treated as errors
core/config.c: In function ‘__libnet_internal__seek_section’:
core/config.c:87: error: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
core/config.c: In function ‘__libnet_internal__get_setting’:
core/config.c:111: error: ignoring return value of ‘fgets’, declared with attribute warn_unused_result
make[1]: *** [core/config.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/home/naman/Desktop/Software/libnet/lib'
make: *** [lib] Error 2
```

Can anyone please explain the error to me in detail, and how to rectify it? Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

https://github.com/sam-github/libnet, that is an ancient libnet version, modern one uses autoconf, do you need to use such an old one?

I'd suggest removing both `-Wall` and `-Werror` from the makefile you are using.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to compile an older library on a newer system, and new warnings have been added to `gcc` since this library was written.

Since the Makefile has warnings treated as errors, (you can tell because it printed `cc1: warnings being treated as errors`) the warning `warn_unused_result` errors are causing the compile to fail.

Your options are to either:

1. Edit the Makefile(s)  and remove any `-Werror` parameter(s)
2. Fix the root cause (unused fgets() return values in the code)
3. Find a different library to use - why do you want to use this (presumably unmaintained) library on your system?